# How to render an array of objects 'webdata' with x and y values in charts in Highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, axios

The `getData()` function in the code as shared in the link which has the value of x and y-axis to be displayed in 'webdata[]' and the values be like this

[image: values of webdata array]

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-pe0tk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The values are not getting displayed in charts where I am using Highcharts library. Could you please let me know the correction in the code so the values below can be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt your data to the format required by Highcharts:

```
series: [{
    data: data.map((el) => ({
        x: new Date(el.timestamp).getTime(),
        y: Number(el.value)
    }))
}],
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/soa25jhu/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type